# how to open multiple windows in a predefined arrangement with a single command

Tags: gui, toolchain

I want to write a single bash script/configuration/whatever to open up multiple windows with a predefined arrangement by executing a single command.

For example, when I get notified about problems with the mail server, I want to execute `connect_mailserver.sh` which opens up a window-container containing

- a window showing `tail -f /var/log/mail.log`
- a window showing `htop`
- a browser window showing all mail-related checks in Nagios
- a shell for doing stuff on that server
- ...

All the windows should be started in predefined positions but I should also be able to move and resize them.

I believe there are many elegant solutions for that, maybe with `screen` or `emacs`. Maybe there is a better tool for that? Do you have a similar solution?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?  (KDE, gnome, lxde, ...). A session manager can store and restore windows (with positions), but it depends on your desktop.

Comment: Oh right, forgot to mention it. I'm using Mate, so all Gnome stuff should work.

Comment: it's been a while, but the old xterm utility used to take a -geometry parameter that let you specify a size and position

Answer (score 2):

Probably not as elegant as you may wish, but I'd use `wmctrl` for this.

```
xterm -T mail.log -e tail -f /var/log/mail.log &
until wmctrl -F -r mail.log -e0,<posx>,<posy>,<width>,<height>
do sleep .1s
done
```

Of course you may use other apps than xterm. `wmctrl` can only match window titles or window IDs. If you cannot set your window title, you'll have to find its ID by `grep`-ing the output of `wmctrl -lp` for the relevant PID.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
xterm -geometry 120x50+100+100 -e 'command'
```

The geometry parameter reads like this: LINESxCOLUMNS+XSTART+YSTART

If you want to find out the geometry parameters, open up several xterms, and start "xwininfo" in another, then clicking on the window you wish to know the geometry parameter of.